# Ruby Nested Loop

Tags: ruby, loops, nested-loops

I have a nested loop2(check2) in loop1(check1) but it seems that nested loop2(check2) only runs once.

Both loops contain the same array. This script is used to check for a duplicate id in check1.

```
check1=["0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "100", "4294967294", "9", "11", "6", "200", "7", "201", "811", "202", "204", "3000", "205", "3001", "3001", "3001"]
check2 =["0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "100", "4294967294", "9", "11", "6", "200", "7", "201", "811", "202", "204", "3000", "205", "3001", "3001", "3001"]
```

Code:

```
check1.each do |check1|
  counter=0
  puts "checking against:"+check1.to_s
  check2.each do |check2|
    puts "checking:"+check1.to_s+"|"+check2.to_s
    if check1 == check2
      counter += 1
    end
  end
  if counter > 1
    dupUID << check1
  end
end
```

The result:

```
checking against:0 <- checking the 1st element in check1
checking:0|0
checking:0|0
checking:0|0
checking:0|1
checking:0|1
checking:0|2
checking:0|3
checking:0|4
checking:0|5
checking:0|100
checking:0|4294967294
checking:0|9
checking:0|11
checking:0|6
checking:0|200
checking:0|7
checking:0|201
checking:0|811
checking:0|202
checking:0|204
checking:0|3000
checking:0|205
checking:0|3001
checking:0|3001
checking:0|3001
checking against:0<- checking the 2nd element in check1
checking:0|3001   <- nested loop2(check2) is not looping again on the 2nd element of loop 1
checking against:0
checking:0|3001   <- loop2 stops at the last element for the remaining elements in check1
checking against:1
checking:1|3001
checking against:1
checking:1|3001
checking against:2
checking:2|3001
checking against:3
checking:3|3001
checking against:4
checking:4|3001
checking against:5
checking:5|3001
checking against:100
checking:100|3001
checking against:4294967294
checking:4294967294|3001
checking against:9
checking:9|3001
checking against:11
checking:11|3001
checking against:6
checking:6|3001
checking against:200
checking:200|3001
checking against:7
checking:7|3001
checking against:201
checking:201|3001
checking against:811
checking:811|3001
checking against:202
checking:202|3001
checking against:204
checking:204|3001
checking against:3000
checking:3000|3001
checking against:205
checking:205|3001
checking against:3001
checking:3001|3001
checking against:3001
checking:3001|3001
checking against:3001
checking:3001|3001
```

Can anyone point out my mistake? Thanks a lot.
Solved: Thanks to all!

```
check1.each do |ch1|
  counter=0
  check2.each do |ch2|
    if ch1 == ch2
      counter += 1
    end
  end
  if counter > 1
    dupUID << ch1
  end
end

puts dupUID
```

Comment: I think your algorithm is flawed. Why are you comparing two identical arrays at all? Even with your approach, to find a duplicate you need to check if `counter > 1`, not `counter > 0` as there will always be 1 matching element from the other array since they are identical. I'm sure there are much better ways of doing this if you can explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: He's trying to find duplicate values within one array. The idea is not that bad, the execution leaves some things to be desired for.

Comment: Hi, Anurag is correct, it should be counter > 1. i need to find the duplicate id in check1. meaning 0 ,1 ,3001 should be flagged out in dupUID

Comment: +1 for helping improve ruby 1.9.2 (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing the `check1` and `check2` arrays because the `do` block variables have the same name as them.

After the inner `do` block, `check2` refers to the last element of the array, not the array itself.

To fix this, rename the block variables to something like `ch1` and `ch2`.

So this explains why the nested loop isn't running as you expect. Actually, your algorithm itself is also flawed. The answer of @floatless gives a better approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you shouldn't write such code. There is a better solution:

```
x = [0, 10, 15]
y = [0, 20, 15]
x & y # => [0, 15]
```

This method returns elements common to the specified two arrays.

**(Updated)** There is another way to do it within only one array:

```
[0, 10, 10, 15, 20].inject({}) 
{ 
    |a, c| a[c] ||= 0; a[c] = a[c].next; a 
}.delete_if { |k, v| v == 1 }.keys
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the misunderstanding, i need to find the duplicate id in check1. meaning 0 ,1 ,3001 should be flagged out in dupUID

Answer (score 1):

Shorter, but not more understandable:

```
check.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |a, x| a[x] += 1; a }.reject { |k, v| v <= 1 }.keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single array `check` and you want to find all duplicate elements within it. Using Ruby 1.9.

```
check.group_by {|v| v}.map { |k, v| v.size > 1 ? k : nil }.compact
```

Explanation:

- `group_by` returns a Hash with key being the number and value being an array of each occurrence.
- `map` returns either nil if the value occurs only once, or the value if it occurs more than once.
- `compact` cleans up all `nil` values.

Here are the step by step results:

```
# after group_by
{"204"=>["204"], "6"=>["6"], "11"=>["11"], "205"=>["205"], "7"=>["7"], "811"=>["811"], "9"=>["9"], "4294967294"=>["4294967294"], "0"=>["0", "0", "0"], "100"=>["100"], "1"=>["1", "1"], "200"=>["200"], "2"=>["2"], "201"=>["201"], "3"=>["3"], "3000"=>["3000"], "202"=>["202"], "4"=>["4"], "3001"=>["3001", "3001", "3001"], "5"=>["5"]}>

# after map
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "0", nil, "1", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "3001", nil]

# after compact
["0", "1", "3001"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had warnings on (`$VERBOSE = true`), it'd notify you about the mistake you had.

IRB for ruby 1.9.1 doesn't allow you to turn on $VERBOSE [at the command line](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1832), but 1.9.2 will.

**Update**: This question lead me to file [this bug/feature improvement](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3634) for ruby. Thanks!